# Smallest Distance-5 Quantum Error Correction Code?

Tags: error-correction

Is it known/proven what the smallest quantum error correction code is that can correct arbitrary two-qubit Pauli errors? I can think of the nested/concatenated 5-qubit code or a 25-qubit version of the Shor (repetition) code, but I am not sure if there are codes requiring fewer qubits.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555303/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608006), section 7, they give an [[11,1,5]] code, and show that it is the smallest you can have.

In general, for these sorts of questions, a great starting point is [Gottesman's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705052). That's where I found this result stated.

Answer (score 0):

Another good place to find codes with your desired parameters is this website: http://www.codetables.de/

The standard format to describe a quantum code is [[n,k,d]], where n is the number of physical qubits whose joint entangled state stores the logical information, k is the number of logical qubits encoded, and d is the distance to which they are protected.

The table is n vs k, where the distance d is the # in the box, so the smallest distance-5 code is the (11,1) entry